# How to jump to a tag in an already open file

Tags: vim, ctags, exuberant-ctags

I know I can jump to a tag generated using ctags with `^]` in the same file and `^w^]` in a horizontal split.

But suppose I already have the file open in a split or tab where the tag exists. Then how can I switch to that buffer and jump to the location of the tag instead of opening a new buffer?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of the splitting `<C-w>]<C-]>` variant can be influenced via the [`:help 'switchbuf'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27switchbuf%27) option. You're looking for `useopen` and maybe also `usetab` values.

However, you cannot easily configure the behavior of the `<C-]>` mapping. If you really want it to open external tags in the same window, but reuse the current window if that tag location isn't yet open, you have to write a wrapper mapping around it.

One approach would be to to a split-jump first, check if the number of windows increased (so no existing window was reused due to `'switchbuf'`), and in that case remove the added window, go back to the original one, and perform a non-split jump instead.